# sql server convert stored procedure to function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help in converting stored procedure to function

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[procBedcount] @place nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
declare @Allbedrahia int;
declare @remain int;
declare @noOccupiedBeds int;
set @place='%' + @place +'%';
set @Allbedrahia =   (select [NopatientsBeds] from departments where Depname ='special')
set @noOccupiedBeds= (SELECT [noOccupiedBeds]   FROM [patientticket].[dbo].[CountsumRahia] );
set @remain = @Allbedrahia - @noOccupiedBeds;
--print ' this ' & @remain
(select depName,noOccupiedBeds,allbeds,remain from AllOccupiedBeds
where AllOccupiedBeds.buildplace like @place
union 
SELECT  [depname],[noOccupiedBeds],@Allbedrahia,@remain   FROM [patientticket].[dbo].[CountsumRahia])

end
```

the result has to be four columns ( depName,noOccupiedBeds,allbeds,remain)

e.g

```
EXEC     [dbo].[procBedcount]
        @place = N'special'
```

return columns of ( depName,noOccupiedBeds,allbeds,remain)

Comment: Where you stuck ? and what you have tried?

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or then write them in all lowercase (select, from) - but pick **one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix and match!

Comment: Why *don't* you create a function? Have you even tried to change `CREATE PROCEDURE` to `CREATE FUNCTION`? Did you check the docs?

Comment: Besides - why use either a procedure or a function? You could create a single query if you just used joins and subqueries. There's no reason at all to have separate queries for `@Allbedrahia`, `@noOccupiedBeds` or  `@remain`. This could be a single query or view, that would be *faster* than the current code

Comment: A function can only return one column. How do you want to use this function?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a table-valued function:

```
   CREATE function [dbo].[funcBedCount]
   (
     @place nvarchar(50)
   )  

   RETURNS @tblReturn table 
   (
     depname nvarchar(50),
     noOccupiedBeds int,
     allbeds int,
     remain int
   )
   AS
   BEGIN

    -- Other initializations ...

    Insert Into @tblReturn (depname, noOccupiedBeds, allbeds, remain )
    (SELECT depName,noOccupiedBeds,allbeds,remain FROM AllOccupiedBeds
        WHERE AllOccupiedBeds.buildplace like @place
    UNION 
    SELECT  [depname],[noOccupiedBeds],@Allbedrahia,@remain 
    FROM [patientticket].[dbo].[CountsumRahia]) 

  END

 RETURN 
 GO
```